# need help cleaning out my Path Variable in Mac

Tags: macos, bash, path, .bash-profile, rvm

when I typed $PATH i noticed a jungle

-bash: /Users/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@Rails/bin:/Users/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/Users/patrick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/patrick/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@Rails/bin:/Users/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/Users/patrick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/patrick/.rvm/bin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin: No such file or directory

how should I go about cleaning this as it seems to be everywhere

update:
I added this function in .bash_profile, so it's more readable

```
function path(){
    old=$IFS
    IFS=:
    printf "%s\n" $PATH
    IFS=$old
}
```

- /Users/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@Rails/bin
- /Users/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin
- /Users/patrick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin
- /Users/patrick/.rvm/bin
- /usr/bin
- /bin
- /usr/sbin
- /sbin
- /usr/local/bin
- /usr/X11/bin
- /Users/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@Rails/bin
- /Users/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin
- /Users/patrick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin
- /Users/patrick/.rvm/bin
- /opt/sm/bin
- /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin
- /opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin
- /opt/sm/bin
- /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin
- /opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin

I guess I have some duplicates due to rvm and jewelrybox.

Comment: What are you trying to keep, what is your goal at the end, and since the folder is missing, is that intentional, or do you want it replaced?

Answer (score 0):

check your .bash_profile for a line similar to this:

```
[[ -s "/Users/USER/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/Users/USER/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

and remove any duplicates of that, that should fix your rvm duplicates.

Comment: I fixed it by commenting out the rvm in both bashrc and bash_profile.  for some reason rvm still shows up